# A recursive_iter_value_t template structure

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to implement a recursive version [`std::iter_value_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t) with C++20 concept so that the base type `T` of nested container like `std::vector<std::vector<...std::vector<T>...>>` can be retrieved. The experimental implementation is as below.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};

template<typename T> requires (!is_iterable<T>)
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail
{
    typedef typename T type;
};

template<typename T> requires (is_iterable<T>)
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail
{
    typedef typename std::iter_value_t<recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>::type> type;
};

template<typename T>
using recursive_iter_value_t = recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>::type;
```

However, I got the error message `'type': use of dependent type name must be prefixed with 'typename'` and I am wondering where the problem is exactly.

The expected output of `recursive_iter_value_t<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` is `int`.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Does it fail to compile? Then show the error. If it compiles but gives the wrong type, state what type that is.

Comment: @cigien Thank you for the comment, the compile error I got is `'type': use of dependent type name must be prefixed with 'typename'`. However, I have no idea where the `typename` keyword need to be placed.

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, not as a comment.